# Installing Composer with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, composer-php, vagrant-windows

I have successfully installed Vagrant along with some boxes on my Windows PC. I got to say it works awesome, creating and destroying VM's with different configurations on the fly.

The only problem I'm facing now is that I want to install composer. But composer requires you to point to the php.exe to do so. I don't want to install PHP on my computer, otherwhise there is no point using Vagrant, right. How do I tackle this problem?

I've seen some articles about using Puppet, but I couldn't make much sense out of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to install PHP (and curl) in your vagrant box. For instance, execute `vagrant ssh` to get SSH access to your box and execute the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y php5-cli curl
$ curl -Ss https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

Now you're ready to use the `composer` command in your vagrant box.

You can improve this by making this part of provisioning, the step where a box is set up when running `vagrant up`. To do this, put the above commands in a shell file (for instance `project/vagrant/provision.sh`):

```
sudo apt-get install -y php5-cli curl > /dev/null
curl -Ss https://getcomposer.org/installer | php > /dev/null
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

Now, configure this shell file as a provision step in your `VagrantFile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # configure the shell file as a provision step:
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant/provision.sh"

end
```

Now, when running `vagrant init`, the shell file is executed and php & composer are installed.

You can also choose to use a box with php and composer pre-installed, like `laravel/homestead`.

Comment: Thanks I got it now. I'm using the homestead box, works perfect.

Comment: Thanks. So when we run composer commands in our vagrant box it will reflect the changes on files on my host windows machine as well ? Also how about git? Do we neet to install git on windows host or in the vagrant box ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is also a vagrant **box with composer pre-installed**. Here is the Github for this box: https://github.com/Swader/homestead_improved.
With Git Bash for windows, navigate to the folder where /homestead_improved was installed.

Run **vagrant up;**, **vagrant ssh** to get inside the VM machine.

Once inside the virtual machine **cd inside the /Code** dir. You can now use composer, for example `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` to install the Laravel installer.

Comment: that's the point my vagrant doesnt have compser pre-installed. what's the use if it doenst have it. why has laravel point us to wrong homestead if this is what they should provide?? PS i havent installed this one yet

Answer (score 0):

Commands to be followed when you are in vagrant homestead in order to update the composer:

1. vagrant ssh
2. cd code (where my laravel projects are)
3. composer selfUpdate --2 [which means composer selfUpdate --versionnumber]